# Connecting to sql database from a different PC

Tags: sql-server, networking

I am implementing a simple POS (Point of Sale) application using C#/WPF. The scenario I am working on is that there will be multiple cashiers running the application in the same physical store. I need to have a centeralized database so that both users connect to the same database to lookup the products and for other operations.

I worked with a company and done the same but all network connectivity and servers were ready at that rime.

How do I connect the two PCs so that one can connect to the main PC which hosts the database. Do I need to install sql on wvery client PC to connect or .NET frame work on client will suffice. What are the options (LAN vs Wireless).

Comment: You do not need to install any database stuff on the clients, but the database server needs to have inbound firewall rules for port 1433 (or whatever you're using) open, you need to configure your SQL server to allow TCP/IP connections, and you need to allow your server to accept connections with SQL server credentials and Windows authentication.  If you're having any specific issues, I can give more specific answers.  But this should be good to start getting started.  You should also make an account on your server with credentials for your clients to connect with.

Comment: Perfect. But there one part related to the network. How do I configure the connectivity between two machines? Thru LAN? Or need modem/router and internet?

Comment: LAN will work.  The most simple way to connect them would be to get a little switch and some Ethernet cables, and just physically connect the machines.  They need to be on the same network subnet to communicate.  If you have a router setup already that all your machines are connected to, you should be able to communicate between the machines already.  Test this by sending a ping.  You can test your connection by making a .udl file on the client machines and then opening it and testing the connection to your server. (just literally make a new file and rename the extension to .udl, then open it)